# reduce a parallel stream of arrays into a single array

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, reduce

i'm trying to reduce a parallel stream of arrays Stream<ArrayList> into a single array ArrayList so
i used the reduce method with accumulator and combiner as follows:-

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add("a1");
        l1.add("a2");
        
        List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        l2.add("a3");
        l2.add("a4");
                
        List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(l1);
        l.add(l2);
        
        Stream<List<String>> stream = l.stream();
        join(stream).forEach(System.out::println);
}

private  static  <T> List<T> join(Stream<List<T>> stream) {
        return stream.parallel().reduce(new ArrayList<>(),  (total, element) -> {
            System.out.println("total: " + total);
            System.out.println("element: " + element);
            total.addAll(element);
            return total;
        },  (total1, total2) -> {
            System.out.println("total1: " + total1);
            System.out.println("total2: " + total2);
            total1.addAll(total2);
            return total1;
        });
}
```

i knew the combiner is used to combine the parallel streams..but it is not working as i expected,
as i got duplicated results as follows:-

```
total: []
element: [a3, a4]
total: []
element: [a1, a2]
total1: [a3, a4, a1, a2]
total2: [a3, a4, a1, a2]
a3
a4
a1
a2
a3
a4
a1
a2
```

so why the result is duplicated ? also is it thread safe to use array list in accumulator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use `flatMap`:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream. (If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.)
>
> This is an intermediate operation.

```
l.stream().flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()); // is [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

or

```
l.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem with your code is that you are mixing functional-style code with side-effects. That doesn't bode well. If you remove the side-effects, the output is as expected:

```java
    private static <T> List<T> join(Stream<List<T>> stream) {
        return stream.parallel().reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (total, element) -> {
            System.out.println("total: " + total);
            System.out.println("element: " + element);
            //total.addAll(element);
            //return total;
            var list = new ArrayList<T>(total);
            list.addAll(element);
            return list;
        }, (total1, total2) -> {
            System.out.println("total1: " + total1);
            System.out.println("total2: " + total2);
            //total1.addAll(total2);
            //return total1;
            var list = new ArrayList<T>(total1);
            list.addAll(total2);
            return list;
        });
    }
```

You should also avoid using `parallel()` unless you have a clear, objective reason to. Parallelism is an overhead, and it only becomes more performant if there is heavy work to do. Otherwise, the synchronization overhead will be a bigger penalty than any gains.

Comment: why the accumulator and the combiner should return a new object in case of parallel processing ?

Comment: @Abdelrahman_Attya It should be free of side-effects.

Comment: When using `reduce`, these defensive copies are unavoidable. In contrast, using `collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll)` is not only shorter, but way more efficient.

Comment: to summarize: reduce designed to perform immutable reduction..we use it when we want to reduce a stream of immutable objects such as (int, double, ..) into a single value..but if we wanted to reduce a mutable object such as (list) we have to make it thread safe by returning a new object each step.